# Arrays of different subclasses for. UITableView data

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a super class Wrapper.

```
class Wrapper {
    var id: Int?
    var createdAt: Date?
}
```

I have two classes that subclass Wrapper, Message and Transaction.

```
class Message : Wrapper{
    /*
        Message properties defined
    */ 
}
class Transaction : Wrapper{
    /*
        Transaction properties defined
    */ 
}
```

Now I have a UITableview that displays a Conversation, and is sourced with data from two arrays of type Message and Transaction. This view will display both Messages and Transactions sorted in order, by createdAt.

The Conversation class looks as such:

```
class Conversation{
    var messages : [Message];
    var transactions : [Transaction];
}
```

My question is, how exactly do I source the cellforItem delegate method with merged data from both arrays, in order by the createdAt variable?

Comment: Merge two arrays (messages, transactions) into a single array and then `sort` it based on `createdAt` then use it for your UITableView

Answer (score 2):

You can store instances of both `Message` and `Transaction` classes by defining the array as `[Wrapper]`, since both are subclasses of `Wrapper`.
You can then sort the array by the `createdAt` property, since both of your classes inherit this property from `Wrapper`.

If you need to display different data in your `UITableViewCell`s based on the exact subclass, you can conditionally downcast the `Wrapper` object in your `cellForRowAt` method and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single array of [wrapper] put both the array of message and transaction in it and sort it by createdAt.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem more than twice. If you really want to not break your data, you can make a `index array` to indexing your datas.

example:

```
enum ArrayType {
    case message
    case transaction
}
let messages = [Int]()
let transactions = [Int]()

var indexes = [Index]()

struct Index {
    var arrayIndex = 0
    var arrayType = ArrayType.message
}

func indexYourData() {
    indexes = []
    var messagesIndexDone = messages.count==0
    var transactionIndexDone = transactions.count==0

    var messageIndex = 0
    var transactionIndex = 0

    var appendTypeIsMessage = false

    while !messagesIndexDone || !transactionIndexDone {
        appendTypeIsMessage = false
        if transactionIndexDone {
            appendTypeIsMessage = true
        } else if messagesIndexDone {
            appendTypeIsMessage = false
        } else {
            appendTypeIsMessage = messages[messageIndex].date > transactions[transactionIndex].date
        }

        if appendTypeIsMessage {
            indexes.append(Index.init(arrayIndex: messageIndex, arrayType: .message))
            messageIndex += 1
            messagesIndexDone = messageIndex>=messages.count
        } else {
            indexes.append(Index.init(arrayIndex: transactionIndex, arrayType: .transaction))
            transactionIndex += 1
            transactionIndexDone = transactionIndex>=transactions.count
        }
    }
}
```